# Adding something at end of file in Python?

Tags: python, jython, file-descriptor

I was just trying to add a string to end of file, but I can't get it to work. I get this error:

```
IOError: (9, 'Bad file descriptor')
```

I get it on line 123. It's in the code below, but marked with #hashcomment:

```
pluginlokacija2 = os.path.realpath("%s/plugins"%os.getcwd())
fo = open("%s/TwistedJobs/config.yml"%pluginlokacija2, "wb")
old = fo.read() #this is line no. 123
fo.seek(0)
fo.write("%s\n- %s\n " % (old, event.getPlayer().getName()))
fo.close
```

Thanks in advance, Amar!

P.S. If you need any more information, please ask for it in comments!

Comment: You opened the file for writing but then tried to read from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file for reading in order to use `.read()`

You have only opened it for writing with `"wb"`.

Use `"rb"` to read, `"wb"` to write, and `"ab"` to append

adding a `'+'` like `"ab+"` allows for simulaneous reading and appending/writing

There is a reference for the different modes [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

Example:

```
with open("filepath/file.ext", "ab+") as fo:
    old = fo.read() # this auto closes the file after reading, which is a good practice
    fo.write("something") # to the end of the file
```

Answer (score 3):

You want `open(filename, "ab+")` :

> The mode can be 'r', 'w' or 'a' for reading (default), writing or
>   appending.  The file will be created if it doesn't exist when opened
>   for writing or appending; it will be truncated when opened for
>   writing.  Add a 'b' to the mode for binary files. Add a '+' to the
>   mode to allow simultaneous reading and writing.

Also with "append" mode you don't even have to read the existing content, seek(0) etc, you can just plain write:

```
bruno@betty ~/Work/playground $ cat yadda.txt
foo
bar
bruno@betty ~/Work/playground $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open("yadda.txt", "a+")
>>> f.write("newline here\n")
>>> f.close()
>>> 
bruno@betty ~/Work/playground $ cat yadda.txt
foo
bar
newline here
bruno@betty ~/Work/playground $
```

Comment: You don't have to read / concatenate / seek(0) with the 'append' mode - just write what you have to.